# Android Studio - FileWriter can't be assigned anything, remains null

Tags: java, android, filewriter

I'm getting a null pointer exception in this method.
Taking a step by step debug and trying a couple different layouts and file writing methods I came to understand that my issue seems to be that I can't manage to find a way to properly assign value to a FileWriter object:

```
public void scriviEccezioneSuLog (String rigaDaScrivere){
    try (FileWriter scrittoreFile = new FileWriter(fileLogUltimaEsecuzione, true)){ //TODO: null pointer exception
        scrittoreFile.write("\n*ECCEZIONE: " + rigaDaScrivere);
    } catch (IOException eccezioneScrituraFile) {
        System.out.println("Eccezione nella scrittura del file di log.");
    }
}
```

The fileLogUltimaEsecuzione File object is defined as:

```
private File fileLogUltimaEsecuzione = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/ultimaEsecuzione.log");
```

During debug the File object does indeed seem to have the intended value, so it is not null.
And yet after the try-with-resources:

```
FileWriter scrittoreFile = new FileWriter(fileLogUltimaEsecuzione, true)
```

scrittoreFile remains null.

Note:
I do not have this problem when trying the same code on a different java IDE (I tried running it on ApacheNetBeans and it is flawless).

EDIT:

Additional information:
The file ultimaEsecuzione.log is instantiated as a class variable and created in the constructor as follows:

```
    try {
        fileLogUltimaEsecuzione.createNewFile());
    } catch (IOException ecccezioneIO) {
        System.out.println("Eccezione IO nella creazione del file di log.");
    }
```

However when I check `.exists()` on the file right after it should have been created I get "false".

Comment: File + FileWriter does no longer work on Android 10/11. Files on the sdcard section have to be retrieved by the MediaStore API. Search for "Android Scoped Storage".

Comment: First try fileLogUltimaEsecuzione.exists() to see if you have access. Tell which Android version in use. Of course File and FileWriter class can be used on Android Q+ too. But you should use the right paths and have the right permissions.

Comment: `"/ultimaEsecuzione.log"` Who put that file there? Put that statement as start of your code please instead of mentioning it afterwards.

Comment: How do I check which version of android I'm using? on build.gradle I see "compileSdkVersion 30", not sure if that is what you're asking for, I'm very new to Android developement.

Comment: Right now it seems I crash whenever I invoke `.createNewFile()` , not sure if it's a permission problem, not even sure how to check that.

Comment: You should look in the Settings of your used Android device to see the Android version of the device. Scroll to the end.

Comment: createNewFile? Then post the stack trace for that exception and or e.getMessage().